# How can I run Rails background jobs with Resque on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, resque, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running my rails app on the [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) platform, which is running a single EC2 instance with Auto Scaling & Elastic Load Balancing.

I'm wondering how to run [`resque`](https://github.com/resque/resque), [`delayed_job`](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) or [`sidekicq`](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/) or some other solution for background jobs on Elastic Beanstalk.

What are the possible options for background jobs on Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: check [this](http://adam.heroku.com/past/2010/4/24/beanstalk_a_simple_and_fast_queueing_backend/)

Comment: @Viren, that is not anything to do with Elastic Beanstalk.

I have been trying to set this up myself, but the only thing I see is the container_commands config which, according to the documentation, runs all the commands before the application is deployed. I'll let you know what I find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to start/stop/restart background jobs could be via init scripts for these tasks. You could have these init scripts triggered as *services* when instances are launched. More about Customizing ElasticBeanstalk containers for services [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-services).

Once done, you could freeze your init scripts by creating an AMI of your instance and then launching instances out of this custom AMI with auto-scaling.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I created a gem, [Active Elastic Job](https://github.com/tawan/active-elastic-job), as a solution for background jobs of Rails applications running on Elastic Beanstalk.
It makes use of Elastic Beanstalk [worker environments](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html), which are intended to be used for background tasks of Elastic Beanstalk applications.

Advantages are:

- You can use the same code base for executing background jobs, no need to branch off a dedicated version of your application to run in worker environments,
- make use of Elastic Beanstalk autoscale capabilities,
- no need to set up external EC2 instances or services to run a
  a queueing backend like `resque` or `sidekiq`,
- no need to customize Elastic Beanstalk containers.
- keep simplicity of Elastic Beanstalk's predefined infrastructure.

However, this gem is only compatible with Rails >= 4.2 applications.

Comment: Hi @tawan, Will it work with Resque?