# Is there a guide for running Resque with a Rails app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, resque

Does anyone know of a clear, for idiots, guide to getting Resque working for a Rails app on [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/)? I'm also just getting my head around moving from development to production with Resque workers on Elastic Beanstalk.

[How can I run Rails background jobs on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662715/how-can-i-run-rails-background-jobs-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk) doesn't mention anything about running the Redis server on Elastic Beanstalk and I feel like there's a big step that I'm missing here.

Comment: Resque is fairly tied to Redis, so this is not currently an option. You can hack it to support Beanstalk if you like though.

Comment: Did you manage to figure out how to start a Redis server and Resque workers?